# (Windows key) + X not working (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

Windows recently installed some Windows Updates, and now [Windows key] + X is not working properly.

It loads this:
[image: win + x not loading properly]
(note, it is very narrow, with no content)

Answer (score 0):

Installing "Cumulative Update for Windows 10 for x64-based Systems (KB3081448)" through Settings (and rebooting) made the [Windows]+X menu display properly.

I tried rebooting before this update was applied and it didn't fix the problem.